# Problems with absolute layout

Tags: java, windowbuilder

I'm a beginner and I used absolute layout in my GUI application using Eclipse WindowBuilder. It works just fine most of the time, but when I minimize or maximize the GUI the content either moves to one side of the page or some part of it vanishes. Can you give a solution for this layout problem? Should it auto adjust itself?

Comment: What are you using to build your GUI SWING, SWT or JavaFX ?

Comment: Don't use Absolute Layout. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: I've rephrased part of your question and added information that was previously only present in the title. Then I made the title actually relevant to your problem. *"I am making a GUI application in eclipse window builder"* does **not** describe the problem you're having.